# Select value which don't have atleast one association

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ItemCategory with category listing and this category is assigned with items. It is like the following:

```
+---------+-------------+
| item_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           1 |
|       2 |           1 |
|       3 |           0 |
|       3 |           2 |
|       3 |           8 |
|       4 |           0 |
|       5 |           0 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Now I need to get the items which don't have any category values. That is in this case it is 4 and 5 which have category as zero. But not not as it is assigned with atleast one category.

I am actually joining these with another tables called Networks and Items so I use query  something like this.

```
SELECT Network.networkname,Items.item_id,ItemCategory.catname 
FROM Network 
JOIN Items 
ON Items.networkid=network.networkid 
JOIN ItemCategories 
ON ItemCategory.item_id=Item.item_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE item_id IN ( 
                   SELECT item_id FROM Table1
                   GROUP BY item_id
                   HAVING MAX(category_id) = 0
                 )
```

Result:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════╗
║ ITEM_ID ║ CATEGORY_ID ║
╠═════════╬═════════════╣
║       4 ║           0 ║
║       5 ║           0 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ca0/2)

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword if you don't want duplicate rows in the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1
WHERE item_id IN ( 
                   SELECT item_id FROM Table1
                   GROUP BY item_id
                   HAVING MAX(category_id) = 0
                 );
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdbe4/3) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from a group by item having count(distinct category)=1 and category=0;
```

Comment: This won't give desired result if there [are duplicate rows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdbe4/4)

Comment: My issue is little complivcated. IT has got JOINS and so the results are repeating. I mean it is showing the item is it HAS zero category without considering the same has atleast one on zero category

Comment: can you make it clearer @Alwin Augustin. Don't understand what you mean (sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql.

```
select item_id
from Table
group by item_id
having max(category_id)=0
and count(item_id)=1
```

Comment: tried this. I have some joins along with. This is giving me the item_id even if it has atleast one category greater than zero.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : missed that. See the updated answer. should work fine.

Comment: got a new set og results. But it also has the same problem.

Comment: can you please update your question with your expected output and with all the cases ? That would be really great.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : if you can please provide some example where the above query fails then i can help you.

Comment: the thing is that it is selecting items which has one category value (non-zero). I don't need items which has atleast one category.